# Regex Expression with special characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I am new with regex expressions in python. 
I am working in a csv file in which I have extracted all the rows.
Now I can't do the searching. I want to find this [[*]], * for any no of characters in between. Any help with it
Currently I am using this in loop

```
    searchObj = re.match( r'\[\[(.*)\]\]', str(row), re.M|re.I)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the `findall` solution should work fine? You need to give an example row, and then we can see why it is not working for you. Assuming you have read your CSV row into a list of columns then the following should be seen:

```
row = ["Col1", "Col2 has [[foo]] in it", "Col3", "Col4 has [[foo]]] and [[bar]]"]

for col in row:
    print re.findall(r'\[\[(.*?)\]\]', col, re.M|re.I)
```

Giving:

```
[]
['foo']
[]
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall` to extract the text presnt inside those brackets, since `re.match` tries to match from the begining of a string.

```
find_lst = re.findall( r'\[\[(.*?)\]\]', str(row), re.M|re.I)
```

**OR**

Use `re.search`

```
find_obj = re.search( r'\[\[(.*?)\]\]', str(row), re.M|re.I)
```

Comment: That didn't work. I need to look up text between [[ and ]] and I am doing something wrong with regex.

Comment: is the text between `[[]]` contain new line chars? If yes, then use `re.DOTALL` instead of `re.M`

Comment: provide the exact input.

Answer (score 0):

```
searchObj = re.match( r'.*?\[\[(.*?)\]\]', str(row), re.M|re.I).groups()
```

`match` matches from beginning.So you can match from beginning and grab the group.